# Cannot find the path of a file.Why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml, scenebuilder

I want to make a "Login" box that looks like this in Scene Builder [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL0xk.png), but when I press run in the main program it gave me a lot of errors and I saw(with the debugger) that it cannot find the path of the fxml file.Why?

This is my Main

```
public class Main extends Application{
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("Application");
    Scene scene = new Scene(initRootLayout());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public AnchorPane initRootLayout() {
    try {

        //Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/D:/Faculta/Lab_ISS/src/main/java/view_FXML/Login.fxml"));
        AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        //  BorderPane rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        return rootLayout;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Muie");
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}
```

}

And **Login.fxml** can be seen in this photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNDEd.png)

Instead of */D:/Faculta/Lab_ISS/src/main/java/view_FXML/Login.fxml"* I also tried

*D:/Faculta/Lab_ISS/src/main/java/view_FXML/Login.fxml(without the first / )

view_FXML/Login.fxml

java/view_FXML/Login.fxml

main/java/view_FXML/Login.fxml

D:\\Faculta\\Lab_ISS\\src\main\\java\\view_FXML\\Login.fxml*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `Login.fxml` file into `src/main/resources` and get the resource using `Main.class.getResource("/Login.fxml");`

Answer (score 0):

The path is not correct. Please consider the [JavaDoc of `Class`, function `getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResource(java.lang.String).
>   Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>     modified_package_name/name
>     Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving a resource from a hard-coded path is problematic. Instead, create a source folder named "resource". (How you do that depends on whether you are using an IDE, you can also create that folder inside your src folder.) This way, resource follow your code through the build and package process.

To find your resource, look at the ClassLoader class' getResource() method. This will search on the classpath for the path you specify and give you a URL, which you can convert to a URI. Then, use new File(uri) or a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the following segment

```
Main.class.getResource(String path)
```

The path shouldn't be an absolute path on the device, it should be a path relative to the classpath. So you need to copy your xml to the same folder your project is running in.